# How do I decide what variable to use for a by-item random effect in linear mixed model?

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model

I am doing a linguistics experiment in which participants judge the acceptability of sentences. I intend to analyze the data using a linear mixed-effects model with crossed random effects for subject and item, but I'm not sure how to decide what counts as an "item" in the relevant way.

To give a simplified example, let's say my experiment has two conditions, A and B. Because I want to know about the linguistic structure of the two different types of sentences and not about the acceptability of the specific sentences chosen, participants see multiple sentences in each condition with different words. I call these *lexicalizations*, but you could call them token sets or something else.

Let's say, simplifying again, that there are two lexicalizations, 1 and 2. Then we will have four items: A1, A2, B1, B2.

To give a more specific example, let's say my experiment is about questions. Condition A has questions with subject-verb inversion and condition B has no inversion. With two different lexicalizations, we'd have four sentences:

- A1. What has John eaten?
- A2. What has Mary speculated?
- B1. What John has eaten?
- B2. What Mary has speculated?

What we're interested in is the difference between A and B, and we want to abstract away from the effect of specific words, which is why I want to include a random effect for item. As I see it, I think there are two ways I could do this:

1. Include a random intercept by Item, where Item is defined as the unique combination of condition and lexicalization. In this simple experiment, there are four Items: A1, A2, B1, and B2, and each would get its own intercept. There's no meaningful way to include a random slope for Item across Condition under this understanding of what an Item is, because an Item can only belong to one Condition.
2. Include a random intercept and slope by Lexicalization in place of the usual by-item random effects. This would give a random intercept for each set of words, allowing for the fact that maybe sentences with *speculated* will be rated lower overall because it's a less common word, and also it would model the fact that the different lexicalizations may react to differently to the two conditions (the acceptability of one set of words may change a lot from one condition to the other, while the other set of words changes less; maybe both B sentences are worse than the A sentences, but B2 is worse than B1).

Which of these options would be the right way to model "by-item" variation in this kind of experiment? Option 2 seems quite reasonable to me, but in the literature people only ever talk about random effects by "item," which leads me to believe most people are doing option 1. However, Option 1 seems to ignore the fact that A1 and B1 are related, modeling each item as if it were independent. Any help here would be much appreciated!